# CSS nth-child 1-6, 7-12, etc

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm attempting at styling children items as follows

1,7,13,etc

2,8,14,etc

3,9,15,etc

4,10,16,etc

5,11,17,etc

6,12,18,etc

What nth-child syntax can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child(6n+1)`, `:nth-child(6n+2)`, `:nth-child(6n+3)`, `:nth-child(6n+4)` etc..

References: http://w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo , http://w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors (thanks @NayukiMinase)

Also, a very good example is here: [Useful :nth-child Recipes - CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/9657-useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Comment: References: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo , http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 2):

read the explanation how `nth-child` works [here](http://css-tricks.com/5452-how-nth-child-works).

you can use 6n+x, where you have to insert appropriate numbers for x.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple equation : **nd + a**

> ```
> here a : first element index
>      n : n
>      d : difference
>
> Example: 1,7,13
> here a : 1
>      n : n
>      d : 6
>     So the pseudo selector will be :nth-child(6n + 1)
> ```